# Clamping a Rotating GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried to clamp a rotation on one of my Gameobjects for over a week now and still have no luck. This is my code so far and what I have tried:

```
        if ((transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 330  ) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)))
    {
    
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime * -1);
    }

    if ((transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 30) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)))
    {
    
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Then I went on and tried this:

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
    
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime * -1);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
    
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3( 0 , 0 , Mathf.Clamp(0, -30, 30) );
```

But I still have no luck. Btw I am using C#
[image: This is the type of game that it looks like and I also wish for the player to rotate back to 0 when no key is pressed]

This is the type of game that it looks like and I also wish for the player to rotate back to 0 when no key is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue was already mentioned:

```
var x = Mathf.Clamp(0, -30, 30);
```

will always return `0`.

In general the best approach for this is simply storing the rotation local and not go through the [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) (local/global doesn't matter for the point)

> Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.

So I would rather use

```
private float zRotation;

private void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        zRotation -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        zRotation += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    zRotation = Mathf.Clamp(zRotation, -30, 30);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, zRotation);
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness!!! Thanks so much this worked!!! At least you were here to fix that problem I have been trying for over a week now. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. And also thanks to all the other people that tried to help. All of you have taught me a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your second code example is much cleaner. The only issue is in your last line:

```
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3( 0 , 0 , Mathf.Clamp(0, -30, 30) ); //this always returns [0,0,0]
```

I think you mean:

```
float rotation = 0;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{        
   rotation -= 1;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    rotation += 1; 
}
float newZAngle = transform.localEulerAngles.Z + (speed*Time.deltaTime*rotation);
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3( 0 , 0 , Mathf.Clamp(newZAngle, -30, 30) );
```

I wrote that without an IDE, so there might be some typos. Also, I haven't used Unity in a while, I'm just going off memory.

Also, I changed rotation using `+=`/`-=` so that when you hold both arrows it doesn't rotate.

Comment: This did help me learn a few more things, but the rotation is really buggy as it spams back and forth between -30 and 30 on the z axis when you press the right arrow. And I have no clue why.

Comment: So far what I can see is if it hits 0 on z axis then it goes to 30. And I do not know why