# Rotating Object is Snapping to a Spot not Moving at a constant speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script so that when I let go of both of the left and right arrow keys it moves back to 0, but it is snapping to 0. This is my code to check that the statements are true:

```
        if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
    if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 0) {
    rotation += speed * Time.deltaTime;     
    }
    else{
        rotation = 0;
    }
    }
```

And this is the script that rotates the GameObject:

```
rotation = Mathf.Clamp(rotation, -30, 30);
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotation);
```

I want to make it so that it moves at the speed of Float: speed and doesnt snap to that rotation.

Comment: as already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69718190/7111561): Don't use the `eulerAngles` property but rather directly work on the float field `rotation` ... though the addition you are making to the code doesn't really change in any way the behavior of the code in my answer ;) limmitting the rotation to happen only with these conditions and then clamping it still results in exactly the same behavior ;)

Comment: I am dumb so i don't really know what you mean. I use the eulerangles to check if it is not at 0. I have only done one side but when i get it working I will make another one but opposite. And again thanks for that other question.

Comment: And also I dont know how else to do what I did with checking the rotation with eulerangles

Comment: What I mean is: What issue are you trying to solve by adding these conditions? There will be no change in the behavior whatsoever so just get rid of them ;) It makes no difference if you make both keys exclusive or simply apply both ... and apply the positive rotation only if the current value is negative even breaks your code ... you would never be able to rotate left or right intentionaly but only towards `0` while the value is different from `0` is that what you want?

Comment: In the photo from the other question you can see what type of game it is. When I click right it tilts right and moves right and the opposite for left. I want it so that when those keys are not pressed that the tilt moves back to 0 at the speed of "speed." So I made it so that if both of the keys aren't pressed then it goes back to the rotation of z=0. (keep in mind that this is in a different script than the movement script and also on a different gameobject.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I think I got now what you want.

You an achieve that by using [`Mathf.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.MoveTowards.html) in order to smoothly move the rotation value towards `0` - regardless whether it is positive or negative - as soon as no button is pressed:

```
var left = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow);
var right = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);

if (left && !right)
{
    rotation -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
else if (right && !left)
{
    rotation += speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
else
{
    rotation = Mathf.MoveTowards(rotation, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

rotation = Mathf.Clamp(zRotation, -30, 30);

transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotation);
```

Note: Now if you press both it is the se as if you press no key at all. If you don't want this behavior you could just remove the excluding conditions (`!left` and `!right`)